# Python Dictionary Condition

Tags: python, dictionary

Still new to Python. I am currently working with a dictionary and have the current code creating keys, values of said dictionary. The are NICK NAME and NAME, and a third category which doesn't matter right now.

```
for row in reader: 
        my_dict[row[0]] = {key: str(value) for key, value in zip(header, row[1:2])}

def get_fullname(nick_name):
    if nick_name in my_dict:
        return my_dict[nick_name]
    else:
        return nick_name
```

With this I am getting a dictionary result when I enter nick_name 'Nico':

```
{'NAME': 'Nicolas'}
```

Which is correct, but how can I get just `Nicolas` rather than the dictionary?

I've done this `return my_dict[nick_name]['NAME']` which works but is not what I want to do.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: "which works but is not what I want to do" - why is it not what you want to do?

Comment: IIUC, you may just want `my_dict[row[0]] = str(row[1:2])`. I assuming, based on the limited information provided, that `row[0]` is the NICKNAME and `row[1:2]` is the NAME.

Comment: Forgot to mention that what I'm thinking is to create another key (?) and I'm unsure of how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the way you create your dictionary -

```
for row in reader: 
        my_dict[row[0]] = str(row[1:2])
```

In this case `my_dict["nico"]` would be `Nicolas` and not `{'NAME':'Nicolas'}` which seems to be what your are looking for.

Comment: My result still has brackets, quotations.. how would I get rid of that part of the result? `['Nicolas']`